# Upload images/files in user specific folder in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to upload images in a folder ( Where folder name is currently logged in username). I am using django login forms.

for example:

currently user is logged in as 'user99'. now i gave functionality where he can upload his images. and when he upload a image, this should save in my local system in his username folder i.e user99.

uploaded image- demo.jpg

target dict - Media/user99/01-02-2022.jpg

In model.py instead of using instance.title , I want to use instance.user. but when i do that i am getting this error.

> mysite.models.Image.user.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Image has no user.

Django version 2.2.5,
Python 3.7.11,
Please guide me. Thank you

my model.py is:

```
def upload_path(instance,title):
    today = str(date.today())
    name = instance.user
    return f'{name}/{today}.jpg'

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CROP_CHOICES)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and views.py is:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            img_obj = form.instance
            return render(request, 'mysite/upload.html', {'form': form, 'img_obj': img_obj})
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'mysite/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py :

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('title', 'image')
```

Comment: Can you use instead of `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` Django's `User` model, imported from `django.contrib.auth.models`?

Comment: @MarioMateaș can you please explain it more.

Comment: I'm saying, in the `Image` class, you could try using `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` instead of `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Also don't forget to `import User from django.contrib.auth.models`

Comment: Done these changes but again getting error : 'mysite.models.Image.user.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Image has no user.'

Comment: Did you try to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and also `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: when i do makemigrations ..i am getting 
'You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to image without a default;'we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: You can either delete your `db.sqlite3` file (but do this *only* if you agree to delete all your database entries and if your current database is used for testing), delete all the files from the `migrations` folder and re-run `makemigrations` and `migrate` *OR*, when you receive that warning, select the first option ("Provide a one-off default now") and type in `timezone.now`. You can edit the entries later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242322/discussion-between-hemant-jaiman-and-mario-matea).

Comment: Thank you for your Idea...it got resolved now. its working fine